# How to measure distance of object using camera?

Tags: android

I referred lot many links [app][1]  but still I am not able to get any point from that I can start my development. I want to measure my image distance  using camera. I found this app . I want to make this type of application not exactly same but quite same but for my requirement I want to measure my image distance using camera.

Can anyone give me/suggest me the right way or any example so that I can get more idea about this requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are the links ? from where did started ?

Comment: This is an unpractical thing (due to approssimative/incorrect responses). You'd better concentrate on something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok you have to

1-drow a "+" or "." in the center of the screen
why ? the bottom of the object that you need to calculate distance from it must be in that "+"

2-access to the G-sensor to know the angle of inclination of the phone (sorry for my english)

3-use a fixed height .. for example the phone must be 1.5 meters of the ground

4-here mathematics get in.. you have angle .. and height ..you can calculate the distance between you and the object.

now you know the steps just translate them to a running application

[image]

Comment: How can you be sure that `the height` is always `1.5 m` (in your example)? Or how do you calculate it? Because `alpha` **is** measurable. I'm not sure the OP wants to always go around with a 1.5 m stick in his hand to lay the phone on.

Comment: if we didn't fix height ..then how do we calculate distance ?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. You can't be sure that the height is always 1.5 m (or any), if you don't use a support of the same length. Which would be ridicolous to carry around. Do you imagine yourself going here and there with a reference stick just to calculate a distance by using your phone? I'd use a flexible meter, instead.

Comment: but the question was "how to calculate distance with camera" ...so i can't answer him wtih "use flexible meter"... i know the problem of the height that gives us wrong measures .. i just gave this man a way ,..

Comment: Your aim is good. But I'd advice the OP that this is an unpractical thing and to concentrate on something else.

Comment: may he could solve this problem, why 1.5 meters .. because because most of us are arround 170cm tall .. so 1.5 meters will be in same level with their neck, so i just gave him a push

Comment: I guess someone how, you could use the motion sensor of the phone to measure the distance from the floor to whatever position you stop the phone, you place the phone at ground level and then start raising it. And that way you wouldn't have to fix the height to 1.5m

Comment: In any case, here an app that uses your approach, for windows phone, but still: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/measure-tools-8/7112e134-05c6-4a87-a08d-68e632ae8b4c

Comment: have some example code to have a base as might implement a mobile application please agradeseria your help

Comment: I would like an example in code to a base'm newly entering the android world Moveable

Comment: i would like to help more, but this is a question answer website..so if you need help in the entire project we cannot do that here

Comment: @CharafEddineMechalikh Can you please guide me how to calculate width of obj from camera?